# Magento 2.1 : How to add Custom button on a custom grid in customer view Adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml, magento-2.1, grid-layout

I have created a custom grid on customer view in admin

```
 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setDefaultSort('model','desc');
        $this->setSortable(true);
        $this->setPagerVisibility(true);
        $this->setFilterVisibility(true);
    }
```

are used to get sorter , pager and filters

How can i add new custom button here above the grid?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your grid.php (where grid columns and sorter etc)

```
 public function getMainButtonsHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getMainButtonsHtml();//get the parent class buttons
        $addButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')
            ->setData(array(
            'label'     => 'Add',
            'onclick'   => "setLocation('#')",
            'class'   => 'task'
        ))->toHtml();
        return $addButton.$html;
    }
```

[SOURCE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5810/move-add-new-button-in-product-tab)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check magento 2 default functionlity to add button in any grid.

```
$this->buttonList->add(
                'nameofbutton',
                [
                    'label' => __('YOUR TEXT'),
                    'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . YOUR ACTION URL . '\')',
                    'class' => 'add'
                ],
                0
);
```

Comment: Already tried not working

Comment: Is this code give any error then specify that.

Comment: that is not any add method in 'magento\module-backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended.php' , anyways found the solution thanks for answering

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Can you please tell us the way to add button in grid . The above code is not working properly.

Comment: @VinaySikarwar Have you tried my solution

Comment: It showing `undefined button list property` error